# Petapoco update datetime error

Tags: c#, datetime, petapoco

I was trying to update a few datetime field using Petapoco, but the update always fail so I look up my SQL profiler and found the following execution statement.

```
    exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [db_Product] SET [aName] = @0, [aDesc] = @1, [EmpID] = @2, [UPCCode] = @3, [isActive] = @4, [isExpendable] = @5, [ProductCatID] = @6, [ProductSubCatID] = @7, [PromoCatID] = @8, 
    [Property1Name] = @9, [Property2Name] = @10, [RackPrice] = @11, [DiscountMethod] = @12, [DiscountAmount] = @13, [SellingPrice] = @14, [Cost] = @15, [CurrencyType] = @16, [qtyPerSaleMin] = @17, 
    [qtyPerSaleMax] = @18, [SupplierID] = @19, [BrandID] = @20, [StartDate] = @21, [EndDate] = @22, [MadeIn] = @23, [TakeStockName] = @24, [LifeCycleName] = @25, [ReOrderQty] = @26, [ReOrderPoint] = @27, 
    [ReOrderDays] = @28, [PreOrderDays] = @29, [aMemo] = @30, [Updator] = @31, [DateUpdate] = @32 WHERE [ProductID] = @33',N'@0 nvarchar(4000),@1 nvarchar(4000),@2 int,@3 nvarchar(4000),@4 int,@5 int,@6 int,@7 
    int,@8 int,@9 nvarchar(4000),@10 nvarchar(4000),@11 decimal(4,4),@12 nvarchar(4000),@13 decimal(4,4),@14 decimal(4,4),@15 decimal(4,4),@16 nvarchar(4000),@17 int,@18 int,@19 int,@20 int,@21 datetime,@22 
    datetime,@23 nvarchar(4000),@24 nvarchar(4000),@25 nvarchar(4000),@26 int,@27 int,@28 int,@29 int,@30 nvarchar(4000),@31 int,@32 datetime,@33 
    int',@0=N'testxxx',@1=N'',@2=0,@3=N'',@4=0,@5=0,@6=1,@7=0,@8=0,@9=N'Color',@10=N'Size',@11=0,@12=N'%',@13=0,@14=0,@15=0,@16=N'TWD',@17=0,@18=0,@19=0,@20=0,

@21=''2013-01-20 12:28:00:000'',@22=''2063-01-20 12:28:00:000'', <--problem

@23=N'TW ',@24=N'週盤',@25=N'新品',@26=1,@27=1,@28=3,@29=1,@30=N'',@31=0,

@32=''2013-02-04 02:45:47:640'' <----problem

,@33=1
```

for some reason, all the datetime fields have **''** and thus causes error in update.

Edit:
C# code, BAL

```
public int Update(int _id, ProductManager _M)
{
    int result = _M.Product.UpdateByID(_id, _M.Product);

    return result;

}
```

C# code, DAL

```
public virtual int UpdateByID(int _id, db_Product data)
{
    data.DateUpdate = DateTime.Now;
     using (var db = new ConnClass().ConnDB())
     {
         var result = db.Update(data, _id);
         return result;
     }
}
```

The BAL **_M.Product.UpdateByID(_id, _M.Product);** send the update to the DAL code for update.
I checked the values in my **ProductManager _M**, the dateTime Values are valid.

**Petapoco Execute command**

```
    UPDATE [db_Product] SET [aName] = @0, [aDesc] = @1, [EmpID] = @2, [UPCCode] = @3, [isActive] = @4, [isExpendable] = @5, [ProductCatID] = @6, [ProductSubCatID] = @7, 
[PromoCatID] = @8, [Property1Name] = @9, [Property2Name] = @10, [RackPrice] = @11, [DiscountMethod] = @12, [DiscountAmount] = @13, [SellingPrice] = @14, [Cost] = @15, [CurrencyType] = @16, [qtyPerSaleMin] = @17, [qtyPerSaleMax] = @18, [SupplierID] = @19, [BrandID] = @20, 
[StartDate] = @21, [EndDate] = @22, [MadeIn] = @23, [TakeStockName] = @24, [LifeCycleName] = @25, [ReOrderQty] = @26, [ReOrderPoint] = @27, [ReOrderDays] = @28, [PreOrderDays] = @29, 
[aMemo] = @30, [Updator] = @31, [DateUpdate] = @32 WHERE [ProductID] = @33
```

I already spent a few days debugging this funny outcome....

Comment: how does your code look like?

Comment: What is your model definition?

Comment: In the end I solve the error.
Actually there is no error, the data is indeed written to the database. But PetaPoco gave the update return int as -1 no matter it is a successful update or not. It seems to be a bug or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Petapoco runs the `UPDATE` statement using ADO.net `ExecuteNonQuery()` and returns the value returned by this function.

The documentation of this function states:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

Comment: So I cannot know if an UPDATE is successful or not since if it returns -1 for both a single row update and a rollback? isn't it confusing?